# Unix Sort with U

Tags: unix, sorting

Anyone knows how this sort works? What do  they [+0.2 -0.42 +0.0 -0.1 -o] mean?

```
CmdString.Format("sort -u +0.2 -0.42 +0.0 -0.1 -o %s %s",
(const char *)TempFilename,
(const char *)TempFilename);
```

Comment: man sort - http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/textutils/coreutils_28.html

Comment: Man is the best tool to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-u` option remove duplicate lines.

`+f.c` and `-f.c` define sorting keys:

- `f` represents a field number
- `c` represent a character number within the field from the beginning of the field when starting with `+` or from the end of the previous field when starting with `-`

Take a look at [sort man page](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) for more precisions about it.

Answer (score 0):

The "-o" is the parameter to define the output file. The rest of the + and - are defining the fields, and offsets in those fields to sort by. [The manual page for sort](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/sort-1.html#scrolltoc) will give all the gory details...

Answer (score 0):

An `info coreutils 'sort invocation'` command reveals that on older systems sort uses an obsolete +POS1 [-POS2] origin-zero syntax for specifying sort keys.

In my opinion, though, the info page is not much more helpful than the `man` page, which is why there hasn't been much explanation so far, beyond a hint that the man page will help.